# MySQL procedure: для чего нужны и как с ними работать

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, для чего MySQL procedure-ы, и как с ними работать?

Answer (score 1):

Хранимые процедуры это набор скомпилированных SQL-команд, хранятся они на сервере. Вся логикаработы с БД помещается в процедуру и пользователям не обязательно знать, что происходит внутри. Пользователям достаточно вызвать хранимую процедуру (возможно с параметрами), чтобы получить некий ответ от сервера.

Значительное преимущество хранимых процедур в том, что они могут как принимать, так и передавать значения.

Существует три типа параметров:

**IN:** По умолчанию. Этот параметр принимается процедурой и может изменяться внутри процедуру, но не может изменятся вне процедуры.

**OUT:** Никакие значения не передаются (это означает что они имеют значение NULL), но они могут быть изменены внутри процедуры, а также изменены вне процедуры.

**INOUT:** Совмещает в себе свойства параметров IN и OUT. Значение может передаваться в процедуру, изменяться внутри процедуры и быть доступным вне процедуры.

Создание процедуры делается с помощью такого синтаксиса:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE имя_процедуры ([параметр_процедуры[,...]]) [характеристика ...] тело_подпрограммы
```

Подробнее можно почитать по этой [ссылке](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).